# How to prevent node delete for a specific node?

Tags: nodes

I want to prevent a specific node from being deleted by anyone except admin. For this specific bundle there are two roles that have full access to the node: admin and manager. A manager can delete any nodes of this content type, but I want one specific node to be locked.

I tried hook_node_delete and it does not work as the delete hook for the specific content type (node) has already run by then.

I tried the [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module and setting of permissions per node, but then when I go to the specific node's edit page the 'delete this content' for the role manager is enabled and greyed out.

I also do not want to just remove the action from the edit form as the node can be deleted in a view bulk operation. Hence I need a catch all solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a catch all solution.

---

On second though, you maybe can create a new content type, say node2, and set the permissions for that content type to admin only.

and if you will ever need more than one admin-only node, you'll have no problems at all.

however i have no experience whatsoever there :p

---

in hook_menu_alter change the 'access callback' for the "node/%nid/delete", since you need it only for a particular node ( say nid=120)

```
$items['node/120/delete'] = $items['node/%nid/delete'];
$items['node/120/delete']['access callback'] = 'custom_function';
unset($items['node/120/delete']['access arguments']);
```

this will prevent that node to be deleted directly.

then you need to remove the delete button from that node form edit (however i don't know the form name).

this should be enough and prevent the deletion "nicely", but you can use hook_delete like pointed out in the other answer to catch everything and everything else that can't be prevented like that.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It definitely looks like my best option.

Comment: I added a maybe-faster solution which may work way better

Comment: I made a custom module and put the above code in it – but this error is thrown out:
ParseError: syntax error, unexpected &#039;{&#039;, expecting &#039;(&#039; in drupal_load() (line 52 of /sites/all/modules/custom/custom_admin/custom_admin.module).
Exception: theme() may not be called until all modules are loaded. in theme() (line 1017 of /includes/theme.inc).
What's wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this out, so take it for what it's worth, but I would try hook_delete.

The code for that one's really simple

```
function hook_delete($node) {
   db_delete('mytable')->condition('nid', $node->nid)->execute();
}
```

I would think wrapping the delete statement in a a permissions check should get you where you need to go.

Comment: That is not how this hook works. It is just there for giving you the option of responding to a node deletion, not preventing it.